# Count sends through Facebook send button

Tags: facebook, plugins, send

Is there any way to know how much people a user has sent a message through Facebook's send
button on a website ?
If not, is there any other way to achieve this kind of thing with another plugin ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This [Document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) clearly mentions that if you register your domain on facebook insights, you will be able to gather analytics about the Send button.